# store field value in cloud function variable

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to get a value from FIRE BASE FIRESTORE and store it in a variable at the cloud function 
because I want to compare two variables in an if statement, using node JS the code that I used is shown below:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(
    (data, response) => {
        const bidder = admin.firestore();
        var old  = bidder.collection(data['collection'])
            .doc(data["doc_id"])
            .get();

        bidder.collection(data['collection'])
            .doc(data["doc_id"])
            .get()
            .then(
                data => {  
                    old =  data.data()['price'];
                }
            );

        var newprice = data["new price"];

        if (newprice <= old) {
            return response.status(500)
                .json({ message: 'Not Allowed.' });
        } else {
            return bidder.collection(data['collection'])
                .doc(data["doc_id"])
                .update(
                    { 
                        name_of_bidder: data["name_of_bidder"], 
                        price: data["price"],
                        phone: data["phone"],
                        capital: true
                    },
                    { merge: true }
                );
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `get()` on a Document Reference returns a Promise, so you have to wait for its end to have access to the data. I think that what you want is this:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(
    async (data, response) => {
        const bidder = admin.firestore();
        var oldDocument = await bidder.collection(data['collection'])
            .doc(data["doc_id"])
            .get();

        var old = oldDocument.data["price"];

        var newprice = data["new price"];

        if (newprice <= old) {
            return response.status(500)
                .json({ message: 'Not Allowed.' });
        } else {
            return bidder.collection(data['collection'])
                .doc(data["doc_id"])
                .update(
                    { 
                        name_of_bidder: data["name_of_bidder"], 
                        price: data["price"],
                        phone: data["phone"],
                        capital: true
                    },
                    { merge: true }
                );
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: the old value is coming as null, besides the if statements never executed, it always goes to else

Comment: @ZeroYah could you share the structure of your firestore please? 
you can try with doc.data() and then using the notation array.